# What does this /etc/fstab entry mean?

Tags: mount, fstab

What does this `/etc/fstab` entry mean?

```
UUID=e67dc3e4-1ac3-4a68-b43f-c77c4dc965d9 /  ext4  errors=remount-ro  0  1
```

Comment: If you're wondering about the part in bold, see: http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount

Comment: If you're wondering why you got downvotes, we encourage research before posting, as @JeffSchaller pointed out.  Also note that `man fstab` might've helped also.

Answer (score 4):

- `UUID=e67dc3e4-1ac3-4a68-b43f-c77c4dc965d9` is the partition, which can be identified either by its name, its label, or its UUID (Universal Unique Identifier) as in this case
- `/` is the mount point; here the partition will be mounted at the root
- `ext4` is the filesystem type; here's the EXT4 journaling filesystem, successor of EXT3 and the most used filesystem for modern Linux machines
- `errors=remount-ro` means that the partition will be mounted read-only should any error occur during the mount
- `0` means that the partition will not be backed up by dump
- `1` defines in which order the filesystem should be checked by fsck for errors